# How to get exit status of piped command from inside the pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, process, try-catch

Consider I have following commandline: `do-things arg1 arg2 | progress-meter "Doing things...";`, where `progress-meter` is bash function I want to implement. It should print `Doing things...` before running `do-things arg1 arg2` or in parallel (so, it will be printed anyway at the very beginning), and record stdout+stderr of `do-things` command, and check it's exit status. If exit status is 0, it should print `[ OK ]`, otherwise it should print `[FAIL]` and dump recorded output.

Currently I have things done using `progress-meter "Doing things..." "do-things arg1 arg2";`, and `eval`uating second argument inside, which is clumsy and I don't like that and believe there is better solution.

The problem with pipe syntax is that I don't know how can I get `do-things`' exit status from **inside** the pipeline? `$PIPESTATUS` seems to be useful only after **all** commands in pipeline finished.

Maybe process substitution like `progress-meter "Doing things..." <(do-things arg1 arg2);` will be fine, but in this case I also don't know how can I get exit status of `do-things`.

I'll be happy to hear if there is some other neat syntax possible to achieve same task without escaping command to be executed like in my example.

I greatly hope for the help of community.

***UPD1:** As question seems not to be clear enough, I paraphrase it:*

I want bash function that can be fed with command, that will execute in parallel to function, and bash function will receive it's stdout+stderr, wait for completion and get its exit status.

Example implementation using `eval`s:

```
progress_meter() {
    local output;
    local errcode;

    echo -n -e $1;

    output=$( {
        eval "${cmd}";
    } 2>&1; );
    errcode=$?;

    if (( errcode )); then {
        echo '[FAIL]';
        echo "Output was: ${output}"
    } else {
        echo '[ OK ]';
    }; fi;
}
```

So this can be used as `progress_meter "Do things..." "do-things arg1 arg2"`. I want the same without eval.

Comment: thanks for fixes, Emil, but using "evil" instead of "eval" was intentional though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `eval` things? Assuming you have one fixed argument to `progress-meter`, you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# progress meter
prompt="$1"
shift

echo "$prompt"

"$@"    # this just executes a command made up of 
        # arguments 2, 3, ... of the script
        # the real script should actually read its input, 
        # display progress meter etc.
```

and call it

```
$ progress-meter "Doing stuff" do-things arg1 arg2
```

If you insist on putting `progress-meter` in a pipeline, I'm afraid your best bet is something like

```
(do-things arg1 arg2 ; echo $?) | progress-meter "Doing stuff"
```

Comment: I missed that out, though. Problems arise when I try to do redirections inplace and/or use compounds and/or use process expansions. Due to these things eval is incredible, cause it works fine, but it's the hell to escape all that stuff when passing it as single string.

Comment: Used your solution, it appears to be best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're trying to achieve,
but you could check the *pipefail* option:

```
 pipefail
                              If  set,  the  return value of a pipeline is the
                              value of the last (rightmost)  command  to  exit
                              with  a non-zero status, or zero if all commands
                              in the pipeline exit successfully.  This  option
                              is disabled by default.
```

For example:

```
bash-4.1 $ ls no_such_a_file 2>&- | : && echo ok: $? || echo ko: $?
ok: 0
bash-4.1 $ set -o pipefail
bash-4.1 $ ls no_such_a_file 2>&- | : && echo ok: $? || echo ko: $?
ko: 2
```

Edit: I just read your comment on the other post. Why don't you just handle the error?

```
bash-4.1 $ ls -d /tmp 2>&- || echo failed | while read; do [[ $REPLY == failed ]] && echo failed || echo "$REPLY"; done  
/tmp
bash-4.1 $ ls -d /tmpp 2>&- || echo failed | while read; do [[ $REPLY == failed ]] && echo failed || echo "$REPLY"; done  
failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your scrips in the pipeline communicate by proxy (much like the Blackboard Pattern: some guy writes on the blackboard, another guy reads it):

1. Modify your `do-things` script so that it reports its exit status to a file somewhere.
2. Modify your `progress-meter` script to read that file, using command line switches if you like so as not to hardcode the name of the blackboard file, for reporting the exit status of the program that it is reporting the progress for.

Comment: `do-things` isn't my script, unfortunately - it can be generic command like `mkdir -p ${MY_TEMP_DIR}`